# ¿Cómo comparar más de dos Strings, equals?

Tags: java, string, if

Tengo que comparar varios `String` y determinar si son iguales o si alguno de esos es diferente.
Tenia pensado hacerlo con un `IF`;

**Ejm**

```
if (A.equals(B,C,D,E,F)
System.out.println("los registros son iguales)
else
System.out.println("los registros no son iguales)
```

Pero parece que no lo puedo hacer así, pues el método `equals` solo me deja poner un valor dentro de los paréntesis. **no quisiera poner varios if.**

Answer (score 2):

Con este método puedes saber si todas las cadenas son iguales.
En caso de que todas sean iguales retorna true, en caso contrario retorna false.
Si le pasas menos de dos cadenas igual regresa false.

```
public boolean sonIguales(String ... cadenas){
    if(cadenas.length<2)
        return false;
    for(int i=1;i<cadenas.length;i++)
        if(!cadenas[i-1].equals(cadenas[i]))
            return false;
return true;    
}
```

Lo puedes mandar a llamar así:

```
sonIguales(B,C,D,E,F);
sonIguales(B);
sonIguales();
sonIguales(B,C,D,E,F,G,H);
```

El método acepta 0 o N parametros.

Comment: Yo cambiaría la comparación por `cadenas[0].equals(cadenas[i])` , pero claro que la diferencia es mínima. También creo que convendría contemplar el caso en que un elemento es nulo (y devolver `false`).  Además (aunque esto es convención opinable) me parecería más natural (y matemámticamente correcto) devolver `true` si hay menos de 2 elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Para darte otro tipo de solución a las brindadas anteriormente te propongo una solución recursiva:

```
public boolean stringsIguales(String[] listaDeStrings, int pos, String primero){
   if(pos >= listaDeStrings.length)
       return true;
   if(!primero.equals(listaDeString[pos]))
       retrun false;
   return stringsIguales(listaDeStrings,pos+1,primero);   
}
```

`listaDeStrings` es un array que contiene todos los strings que quieres comparar, `pos` es un parámetro que se utiliza para acceder a las posiciones del array. Cuando llames a la función este parámetro siempre debería estar en 0. Y `primero` es el string que se va a comparar con todos.

Answer (score 1):

Si se tiene más de dos `String` , vendría a ser una colección y no sería correcto comparar variable por variable y así. Propongo tener una Lista con los elementos y trabajar con esta.

Para esto haríamos uso de `Stream`, empleamos el método [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) que básicamente retornará un valor `booleano` , `True` si la lista coincide con el parámetro *predicado* o si la lista está vacía *(para esto se validó antes con un `if` y no tener problemas con el indice 0)*  y `False` si no coincide.

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("os");
lista.add("os");
lista.add("os");
if(!lista.isEmpty()){
    // Si desea ignorar mayúsculas o minúsculas
    //if(lista.stream().allMatch(lista.get(0)::equalsIgnoreCase))
    if(lista.stream().allMatch(lista.get(0)::equals))
        System.out.println("Elementos Iguales");
    else
        System.out.println("Elementos no son Iguales");
}
else
    System.out.println("Lista Vacía");
```

Answer (score 0):

si solo quieres ver si alguno es diferente seria algo asi:

```
String cadenaAComparar;
String a,b,c;
if(cadenaAComparar.equals(a) && cadenaAComparar.equals(b) && cadenaAComparar.equals(c)){
//todas son iguales
}else{
//alguna es distinta
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste mucho.
otra pregunta si quisiera saber cual de ellos es diferente?

Answer (score 0):

Un método como este también serviría para comparar si tres cadenas son iguales:

```
    private static boolean sonIguales(String a,String b,String c)
    {
        return Objects.equals(a,b) && Objects.equals(b,c);
    }
```

Se podría mejorar para que admita `n` cadenas y las compare...

---

#### `Ejemplo completo:`[`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/LNT3283)

```
import java.util.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        //Prueba de comparación textos iguales
        if (sonIguales("texto1","texto1","texto1")){
            System.out.println("Iguales\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO Iguales\n");

        }

        //Prueba de comparación textos no iguales

        if (sonIguales("texto1","texto2","texto1")){
            System.out.println("Iguales\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO Iguales\n");

        }
    }

    // Nuestro método

    private static boolean sonIguales(String a,String b,String c)
    {

        return Objects.equals(a,b) && Objects.equals(b,c);
     }

  }
```

---

#### `Resultado:`

```
// sonIguales("texto1","texto1","texto1")
Iguales

// sonIguales("texto1","texto2","texto1")
NO Iguales
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera, sirve para comparar cada palabra de un arreglo con todas las palabras del mismo arreglo y devuelve la palabra diferente en el caso de que la halla y en el caso de ser iguales retorna null:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Comparar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Comparar();
}

public Comparar() {
    String palabra = comparar("hola","hola","hola","holas","hola");
    if(palabra == null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las palabras son iguales");
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La palabra diferente es: "+palabra);
    }
}


public String comparar(String ... palabras){
    for(int x = 1; x < palabras.length; x++){
        if(!palabras[0].equals(palabras[x])){
            return palabras[x];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: No tiene sentido comparar todos los pares (n^2 operaciones). Basta con comparar todos con (digamos) el primero (n-1 operaciones)

Comment: XD sii se me fue la mano y la mente por payaso, tienes razon. Gracias por la correccion y por destruir mi confianza al programar :(